# Does SQL have a way to group rows without squashing the group into a single row?

Tags: group-by, mariadb, grouping

I want to do a single query that outputs an array of arrays of table rows. Think along the lines of `<table><rowgroup><tr><tr><tr><rowgroup><tr><tr>`. Is SQL capable of this? (specifically, as implemented in MariaDB, though migration to AWS RDS might occur one day)
The `GROUP BY` statement alone does not do this, it creates one row per group.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking of…

```
SELECT * FROM memes;

+------------+----------+
| file_name  | file_ext |
+------------+----------+
| kittens    | jpeg     |
| puppies    | gif      |
| cats       | jpeg     |
| doggos     | mp4      |
| horses     | gif      |
| chickens   | gif      |
| ducks      | jpeg     |
+------------+----------+

SELECT * FROM memes GROUP BY file_ext WITHOUT COLLAPSING GROUPS;

+------------+----------+
| file_name  | file_ext |
+------------+----------+
| kittens    | jpeg     |
| cats       | jpeg     |
| ducks      | jpeg     |
+------------+----------+
| puppies    | gif      |
| horses     | gif      |
| chickens   | gif      |
+------------+----------+
| doggos     | mp4      |
+------------+----------+
```

I've been using MySQL for ~20 years and have not come across this functionality before but maybe I've just been looking in the wrong place `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: MariaDB does not support ARRAYs as far as I know. Can you provide an example of the data you want to store/retrieve?

Comment: @TheImpaler I added an example

Comment: A simple `ORDER BY` would produce the result you want: `SELECT * FROM memes ORDER BY file_ext`. However, I'm not sure if this answers your question. Maybe you want extra aggregations, like counts, row numbering, etc. MariaDB 10.2 and newer has a ton of extra features.

Comment: @TheImpaler `ORDER BY` does not group the results, it just returns a flat list. It should look something like `[[a, b, c], [d, e], [f], [g, h, i]]`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an array rendering such as the one you want, but you can simulate it with multiple `GROUP BY` / `GROUP_CONCAT()` clauses.

For example:

```
select concat('[', group_concat(g), ']') as a
from (
  select concat('[', group_concat(file_name), ']') as g
  from memes
  group by file_ext
) x
```

Result:

```
a                   
---------------------------------------------------------
[[puppies,horses,chickens],[kittens,cats,ducks],[doggos]]
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5fcc98acd1fb711d1aa0b664e369c9f7).

You can tweak the delimiters such as `,`, `[`, and `]`.

Comment: A good start, though this would still require post-processing in the calling software to parse the string into arrays, and that would be more work than looping over the flat list and checking the value of the group column, and manually create the arrays. Looks like the answer might be "no", then.

Comment: Do you know of any other SQL engines that have a concept of arrays?

Comment: @NicholasShanks PostgreSQL implements arrays quite well.

Comment: @NicholasShanks Since MariaDB doesn't have arrays you can't produce them. This one (VARCHAR) is one option that could be useful. Anoher viable option could be to produce a JSON object: this one could include an array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ... ORDER BY file_ext` will come close to your second output.

Using `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` would let you do subtotals under each group, which is not what you wanted either, but it would give you extra lines where you want the breaks.

Comment: Yep, it seems SQL doesn't have a concept of groups of rows within a table, so I didn't miss anything.